# Bernzomatic oxygen bottles to oxygenate beer

Tags: beer, oxygenation

I bought a cylinder of [Bernzomatic](http://www.bernzomatic.com/item.html?id=49) Oxygen on the advice of my local homebrew store. They sold me an adapter kit (w/ air stone) and I got the cylinder from Lowes (tool section).

[Picture of adapter](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/brewing/brewing-equipment/fermenting-equipment/aeration/oxygenation-kit.html)

Firstly I tried attaching the adapter directly to the cylinder which caused massive leakage through the threads. Applying teflon tape (lots) helped but it was still leaking a bit. Exhausted the entire bottle for less than 5 minutes.

If anyone is using O2, how is it done?

Comment: Pictures would help. Are the fittings brass, plastic ?

Comment: I've used such O₂ cylinders with the commonly-available homebrew adapters in the past. There should be no leakage. Pictures and/or web links would help.

Comment: are you sure you had the regulator turned off before attaching? and it shouldnt need teflon tape, the O ring should seal it, when attached correctly.
 I have used similar for propane camping stoves.

Comment: I have to chime in, too, and say I use that exact oxygen bottle with that exact oxygenation kit, and it works fine. I was able to oxygenate at least six batches (didn't keep count) with one bottle following the instructions. Yours might be defective.

Comment: Apparently there is something missing from the adapter. I'll be getting a replacement soon.

Comment: Is that a food-safe oxygen source? I didn't see any mention of it on the web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the attachment back to the homebrew store and they replaced it and attached trhe replacement themselves. Since then I have used the bottle for several batches. I guess it was a defective gasket.